# Need a help to Run reports without html pagination

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi

Currently, I am using Cognos BI 10.1.1. Now I want to write a program to execute a report in HTML format using Cognos SDK. But I am getting partial data instead of entire data but in PDF all data is displaying.
My suspect is on Pagination. Can anyone help me to resolve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.